# How do I center and format a Vietnamese poem?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, italic, chinese, poetry

So I need help with formatting a poem with Hanzi characters. The fact is that I need the poem to be italicized **except** the chinese character within. Also it has to be center aligned. Here's my attempt at centering the poem. As you can see it's not going well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{NotoSerifHK-Regular}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\setmainfont{NotoSerif-Regular}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            Ngày Xuân (日) con én đưa thoi,\\
            Thiều quang chín chục đã ngoài sáu mươi.\\
            Cỏ non xanh tận chân trời,\\
            Cành lê trắng điểm một vài bông hoa.\\
            Thanh minh trong tiết tháng ba,\\
            Lễ là tảo mộ, hội là đạp Thanh.\\
            Gần xa nô nức yến anh,\\
            Chị em (三人) sắm sửa bộ hành chơi xuân.
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        Tháng giêng là tháng ăn chơi,\\
        Tháng hai cờ bạc, tháng ba hội hè.
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE should output nothic in italics, because you never tell LaTeX to use an appropriate font. If I use `Noto Serif CJK TC` and `Noto Serif` as fonts and add `\itshape` at a reasonable position in your code, the text will be in italics, the Chinese characters will be upright. So, I cannot reproduce your problem. Apart from that, why do you use a `tabular` and not a probably more suited environment such as `center` or `quote` (without or with `\centering`)?

Comment: What is nothic?

Comment: I meant „nothing“. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to do, actually, but I believe you should define your own environment.

If you define `ItalicFont` to be the same as the upright one in the CJK part, you even avoid an annoying warning. I'm afraid that you can't stop the very annoying warning about missing patterns for Vietnamese, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho}[ItalicFont=*]

\newenvironment{myverse}[1]
 {% end paragraph and add some space
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  % apply the declarations
  #1
  % start a tabular
  \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
 }
 {% end the tabular
  \end{tabular}%
  % finish off
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{myverse}{\itshape}
Ngày Xuân (日) con én đưa thoi,\\
Thiều quang chín chục đã ngoài sáu mươi.\\
Cỏ non xanh tận chân trời,\\
Cành lê trắng điểm một vài bông hoa.\\
Thanh minh trong tiết tháng ba,\\
Lễ là tảo mộ, hội là đạp Thanh.\\
Gần xa nô nức yến anh,\\
Chị em (三人) sắm sửa bộ hành chơi xuân.\\[2ex]

Tháng giêng là tháng ăn chơi,\\
Tháng hai cờ bạc, tháng ba hội hè.
\end{myverse}

\begin{myverse}{\centering\itshape}
Ngày Xuân (日) con én đưa thoi,\\
Thiều quang chín chục đã ngoài sáu mươi.\\
Cỏ non xanh tận chân trời,\\
Cành lê trắng điểm một vài bông hoa.\\
Thanh minh trong tiết tháng ba,\\
Lễ là tảo mộ, hội là đạp Thanh.\\
Gần xa nô nức yến anh,\\
Chị em (三人) sắm sửa bộ hành chơi xuân.\\[2ex]

Tháng giêng là tháng ăn chơi,\\
Tháng hai cờ bạc, tháng ba hội hè.
\end{myverse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you make the () non italic as well?

Comment: @AdrikIvanov You can always make parts of otherwise italic text non-italic using `\textit{this is italic, \textup{this is not,} this is italic again}`. So, you can say `\textup{(日)}`, for example to make sure the parenthesis are upright.